# The usage of {% url ...%} vs {{ ... }} in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've been practicing Djnago and for that, I was building a blog. While in the process of building it, I was faced with an error, while using the following code:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_post' post.slug %}">
    {{ post.title }}
</a>
```

While studying and doing other courses something like this would work fine. But now, it will raise this exception: ***NoReverseMatch***.

[image]

If I use this code though, it will work just fine:

```
<a href="{{ post.slug }}">
    {{ post.title }}
</a>
```

While working in different projects the first way would work fine, but this time, it doesn't.

**My question is why?**

Here is the code in my **urls** and on my **views**. Maybe the mistake is here, not somewhere else.

If anyone can explain why this is happening, or where I'm going wrong, it will be greatly appreciated

**urls**:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
    path('<slug:post_slug>/', views.blog_post, name='blog_post'),
]
```

**views**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('- 
    created').filter(published=True)
    data = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', data)

def blog_post(request, post_slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=post_slug)
    data = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', data)
```

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**. `NoReverseMatch` is not sufficient to debug the issue.

Comment: @Selcuk At least (hopefully? I didn't test) there's a [example].

Comment: @user202729 No, there is not. We don't know the input (`post`) that caused the issue for starters. Also an MCVE is not an excuse for missing debugging information (such as the error message).

Comment: @Selcuk thank you! I've updated the question with a print of the error message given by Django. I believe it is clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.your problem is that you have a namespace in your urls.py then in your href you should add that namespace('blog').

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog_post' post.slug %}">
    {{ post.title }}
</a>
```

this

```
 <a href="{{ post.slug }}">
    {{ post.title }}
</a>
```

this code above was working because you are located inside the home page and when you add this(href="{{ post.slug }}" in the a tag) it will just call the current url +"/<'slug:post_slug/' and this is a valid url.but this is a very bad option.use the the first option.
to learn about this refer to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces.

Comment: More specifically, the question was "why?", not "can you give me code?"

Comment: @user202729 thanks for your advice.the problem is that my english is not so good.but i have edited again my answer.

Comment: It is bad practice to perform such operations in templates

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, you should use:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url
The less logic in the templates, the better for the application.
It is difficult to write tests on logic that is contained in templates.

You should add a method to your model:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post()
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:blog_post', kwargs={'post_slug' : self.slug})
```

In the reverse function you need to add an application namespace.
In your case, it's a blog.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#introduction

and then in template use:

```
{{ post.get_absolute_url }}
```

From documentation:

> The logic here is that if you change the URL structure of your objects, even for something small like correcting a spelling error, you don’t want to have to track down every place that the URL might be created. Specify it once, in get_absolute_url() and have all your other code call that one place.

Comment: While technically correct, this is not an answer to the question asked. We don't know the reason OP's code fails and `reverse` will fail similar to `{% url %}` under the same circumstances.

Comment: I added the information that application namespace
 should be added. I wrote working code, but I actually forgot that it might not be obvious. @Selcuk

Comment: Your answer works well for me. I'm choosing the other answer as the right one for familiarity but, yours seem to be a good choice as well. Still trying to figure out, which one is a better practice. I'll be looking into this one. Thank you!